# looping diffulties with 2 csv files

Tags: python-3.x

Ok this is the last question about csv files and looping.

So I with my loops I want to do the following.

This is the csv file of students I have made into lists.

## File 1

```
['Needie Seagoon', '57', '', '83', '55', '78', '', '91', '73', '65', '56', '', '', '']
['Eccles', '', '98', '91', '80', '', '66', '', '', '', '77', '78', '48', '77']
['Bluebottle', '61', '', '88', '80', '60', '', '45', '52', '91', '85', '', '', '']
['Henry Crun', '92', '', '58', '50', '57', '', '67', '45', '77', '72', '', '', '']
['Minnie Bannister', '51', '', '97', '52', '53', '', '68', '58', '70', '69', '', '', '']
['Hercules Grytpype-Thynne', '', '78', '62', '75', '', '67', '', '', '', '48', '56', '89', '67']
['Count Jim Moriarty', '51', '', '68', '51', '66', '', '55', '72', '50', '74', '', '', '']
['Major Dennis Bloodnok', '', '54', '47', '59', '', '48', '', '', '', '66', '58', '53', '83']
```

I then have another csv file with the max scores of each course:

## File 2

```
CITS1001    95
CITS1401    100
CITS1402    97
CITS2002    99
CITS2211    94
CITS2401    95
CITS3001    93
CITS3002    93
CITS3003    91
CITS3200    87
CITS3401    98
CITS3402    93
CITS3403    88
```

So what I want to do and have been trying very hard to achieve is try and divide each student score by the max score of the course.

so for each student, the value going horizontal, I want it to divide by the values of the other value vertically.

For example:

['Needie Seagoon', '57', '', '83', '55', '78', '', '91', '73', '65', '56', '', '', '']

I want 57/95 , skip, 83/100, 55/97... you get where I'm going?

I want to do this for every name In the file. This code might be familiar to some of you but I know I'm doing something wrong.

```
def normalise(students_file, units_list):
    file1 = open(students_file, 'r')
    data1 = file1.read().splitlines()
    
    file2 = open(units_list, 'r')
    data2 = file2.read().splitlines()
    
    
    for line in data1:
        line = line.split(",")
        for row in data2:
            row = row.split(",")
            for n in range(1, len(row), 2):
                for i in range(1, len(line), 1):
                    if line[i] == '' :
                        pass
                    else:
                        answer = int(line[1]) / int(row[n])
        
    file1.close()
    file2.close()
```

I'll show you some of the output(goes on for a very long time).

output:

## 1st loop

```
0.6
none
0.8736842105263158
0.5789473684210527
0.8210526315789474
none
0.9578947368421052
0.7684210526315789
0.6842105263157895
0.5894736842105263
none
none
none
```

## 2nd loop

```
0.57
none
0.83
0.55
0.78
none
0.91
0.73
0.65
0.56
none
none
```

I understand that I have readline() but when I do readlines(), I cant strip the /n as it doesn't allow me to and the end='' makes the code messy. This output is saying that every value in the students row is getting divided by 95 then looping back to the start and looping every value by 100 and so on. How can I make the first value divide by 95, second by 100 and so on.

Sorry for the long explanation/question but I get told to explain myself more.

thanks.

Comment: Can you provide the original `students_file` ?

Comment: How do I upload the file?

Comment: Copy file content and paste it in the question.....

Comment: the second file is exact from the csv, the first file pastes weirdly so I made it into a list, imagine each element is a cell and its identical to the csv file, there are no headers other then the names.

Comment: I am just confused why you have so many irregular empty element in your list...

Comment: they are empty cells